# Parse plain email address into 2 parts

Tags: c#

How do I get the username and the domain from an email address of:

```
string email = "hello@example.com";
//Should parse into:
string username = "hello";
string domain = "example.com";
```

I'm seeking the shortest code to do this, not necessarily efficient.

---

Scenario: I want to parse it in my ASP.NET MVC view so I can cloak it.

Comment: email.Split('@')[0] and email.Split('@')[1]

Comment: Use Brian Bondy's solution.  Anything that uses `string.Split` is going to fail in many cases.  Now where's the obligatory (and hopelessly wrong) regex solution?

Comment: @Jim: /hello/ and /site\.com/

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Use the [MailAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress.aspx) class

```
MailAddress addr = new MailAddress("hello@site.example");
string username = addr.User;
string domain = addr.Host;
```

This method has the benefit of also parsing situations like this (and others you may not be expecting):

```
MailAddress addr = new MailAddress("\"Mr. Hello\" <hello@site.example>");
string username = addr.User;
string host = addr.Host;
```

In both cases above:

```
Debug.Assert(username.Equals("hello"));
Debug.Assert(host.Equals("site.example"));
```

At the top of your file with the rest of your using directives add:

```
using System.Net.Mail;
```

Comment: Small note: MailAddress is not available on a Windows Store App.

Answer (score 15):

```
String[] parts = "hello@example.com".Split(new[]{ '@' });
String username = parts[0]; // "hello"
String domain = parts[1]; // "example.com"
```

Comment: For a missing semicolon? Taking the compilation error a little too seriously, aren't we?

Comment: And yes, I always expect actual code posted on SO to be at least compilable. Otherwise say it's pseudocode.

Answer (score 8):

```
string username = email.Split('@')[0];
string domain = email.Split('@')[1];
```

Comment: Event though this demonstrates the idea nicely, it sets a bad example.  Calling `Split` twice is inefficient and requires more maintenance in the future when things change.

Comment: "I'm seeking the shortest code to do this, not necessarily efficient." :)

Comment: Well, that's usually why we have to upgrade our computers every one or two years.

Comment: @detunized agreed... I would not do it this way, but this is what he wanted

Answer (score 2):

Use this it will not give exception when no domain or username found instead it will give null value for that,

C# :

```
string email = "hello@example.com";

string username = email.Split('@').ElementAtOrDefault(0);
string domain = email.Split('@').ElementAtOrDefault(1);
```

VB :

```
Dim email as String = "hello@example.com";
Dim username = email.Split("@".ToCharArray()).ElementAtOrDefault(0);
Dim domain = email.Split("@".ToCharArray()).ElementAtOrDefault(1);
```

Comment: This does not give a null value. If the email given is listed as "helloexample.com" the username line will return "helloexample.com"

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = email.IndexOf('@');
if (i >= 0)
{
    username = email.Substring(0, i);
    domain = email.Substring(i + 1);
}
```