# Spliting string in LINQ and using 2nd Index value

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, .net, linq

I am stuck to split an Email to get the Domain of Email in group by clause of LINQ to group the data by domain.
My LINQ is

```
(
    from u in DbContext.UserProfiles
    join ap in DbContext.AspNetUsers
        on u.PhoneNo equals ap.PhoneNumber
    where u.IsVerified == true
    let domainName = ap.Email.Split('@').Skip(1).FirstOrDefault()

    /*ap.Email.Split('@')[1]  
    ap.Email.Substring(ap.Email.IndexOf('@') + 1, ap.Email.Length) 
    ap.Email.Split('@').ElementAt(1) 
    GetDomainHost(ap.Email)*/

    group ap by new
    {
        DomainName = domainName 
    }
    into grp
    select new
    {
        grp.Key.DomainName,
        TotalUsers = grp.Count()
    };
)
```

*NOTE: I have tried commented code as well but al showing me same exception that `LINQ not supported`*

I need to split Email and get the Domain which will be on 2nd Index.
How can I solve this?

**Edit** :

Exception I am facing to convert is

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   ElementAt[String](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String],
>   Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store
>   expression.

Actually, I am trying to convert this `SQL`

```
select dbo.GetDomainFromEmail(ap.Email) as 'Domains', Count(*) as 'Total Users' 
from AspNetUsers ap 
join UserProfile up 
    on ap.PhoneNumber = up.PhoneNo and 
    up.IsVerified = 1 
group by dbo.GetDomainFromEmail(ap.Email)
```

to `LINQ`. and `dbo.GetDomainFromEmail(ap.Email)` is a function and defined as 
`Substring(ap.Email, Charindex('@', ap.Email)+1, LEN(ap.Email))`.

Comment: You should give us actual full error messages or it's very difficult to help. I am guessing the problem is Entity Framework though, it's trying to figure out what to do with your query. Your only solution here is to materialise the data to a local, in-memory list and then group by that.

Comment: You may also look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443225/parse-plain-email-address-into-2-parts) to see how to split an email into parts properly

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski your given thread only explain splitting strings, but my question is how can I do this in `LINQ`. Because `LINQ` does not recognize all of my attempts of splitting strings. Provided in my Question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using regex-groups. Here an example:

```
string emailAdress = "yourEmailHere@theDomain.net";

Regex pattern = new Regex("@(?<domain>[a-zA-Z0-9]*)");
Match match = pattern.Match(emailAdress);
string domain = match.Groups["domain"].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to first execute the query before using `Split` as **Linq to Entity** does not support `Split` method. So you can use `AsEnumerable` to make the select occur in memory instead of EF.

So we can get all domain names at first:

```
var emails = (from u in DbContext.UserProfiles
join ap in DbContext.AspNetUsers
    on u.PhoneNo equals ap.PhoneNumber
where u.IsVerified == true
select new
{
    Email = ap.Email
}).Distinct().AsEnumerable();
```

Then we can get all domains from `emails`.

**UPDATE:**

In addition, if you would like to avoid loading data into memory, then you can [execute plain SQL query](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/raw-sql-query-in-entity-framework.aspx) to get all domains:

```
var results = db1New.Database.SqlQuery<string>("
    SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(up.Email, CHARINDEX('@', up.Email) + 1, LEN(up.Email) ) AS Domain
    FROM dbo.UserProfiles up 
    GROUP BY SUBSTRING(up.Email, CHARINDEX('@', up.Email) + 1, 
    LEN(up.Email))").ToArray();
```

Comment: I don't just need all domains, I need the count of every domain as well. That's why I have to apply aggregate `group by` on email domains.

Comment: @Fahad I suggested to get all domains as far I know there is no `Split` function in **Linq To Entities**.

Comment: Yes, there is no split in LINQ To Entities

Comment: @Fahad so you need to get data into memory and then use `Split` methd

Comment: But that takes a lot of time to get it into `ToList()` or `AsEnumerable()` then performing `split()` on it.